# Heroku setting up SendGrid trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid, cloud9

I've been having trouble with this for faaarrrrr too long. I've looked at literally countless questions similar to mine and can't seem to get any of them to work.

I've been using cloud9 ide and pushing to heroku attempting to just send a simple email using SendGrid. I am pretty sure the problem is in the settings in production.rb or in the way I've set up heroku with SendGrid but I am just at my wits end.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://tranquil-plateau-41839.herokuapp.com' }
```

I've put this in production.rb file in the enviroment folder.

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now
```

This is sitting in my user.rb file inside an if statement that executes if the user saves. I've tried a million different combinations to get this to work and it doesn't seem to want to.

This is what I get from heroku -logs

```
2017-11-18T04:40:06.396183+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.1ms)  COMMIT
2017-11-18T04:40:06.396635+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 140ms (ActiveRecord: 37.3ms)
2017-11-18T04:40:06.396468+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://tranquil-plateau-41839.herokuapp.com/login
2017-11-18T04:40:06.459084+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/login" for 173.28.213.164 at 2017-11-18 04:40:06 +0000
2017-11-18T04:40:06.460969+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
2017-11-18T04:40:06.462953+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (1.1ms)
2017-11-18T04:40:06.464328+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-11-18T04:40:06.465391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=tranquil-plateau-41839.herokuapp.com request_id=e079f0c1-4408-4c29-b4a0-0707004e02fc fwd="173.28.213.164" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=2823 protocol=http
2017-11-18T04:40:06.397638+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=tranquil-plateau-41839.herokuapp.com request_id=f851ddf6-d55a-43b9-9631-a17e98fa47a4 fwd="173.28.213.164" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=147ms status=302 bytes=1064 protocol=http
```

It doesn't seem to be giving errors and when I look at my SendGrid site it doesn't have any activity not even requests or bounces. So I assume something is wrong with my configurations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated I am losing my mind.

****** Updated *******

This is now my production.rb file

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "http://tranquil-plateau-
    41839.herokuapp.com" }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.force_ssl = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 587,
    :domain => 'heroku.com',
    :user_name => 'app***@heroku.com',
    :password => 'secret',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

This is my development.rb file

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:'localhost', port: '3000'}
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port => 2525,
    :domain => 'localhost:3000',
    :user_name => 'app****@heroku.com',
    :password => 'secret',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I have a strong feeling it is my domain or port that is the issue in production. However, when in development the emails go through successfully. I've tried a million different variations and I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: If more information is needed let me know and I'll get it for you.

Comment: The `user_name` and `password` should be your Sendgrid username and password. You should also be setting them as environment variables instead of hardcoding them, because unless your repository is private they'll be viewable by others.

If you're not getting an error the message is probably not being delivered, so I'd check your user.rb file.

Comment: My problem is I can send emails when I'm in the development environment but when I push to heroku it wont send. I know or atleast highly suspect it being something to do with the domain/port information but cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: A few throw-it-at-the-wall suggestions: 1) set `domain` to `"heroku.com"`, 2) change `port` to `587` and 3) set `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` to `{ host: "http://tranquil-plateau-41839.herokuapp.com" }`. Also, you should really, _really_ set `config.force_ssl` to `true` in production.rb and update all of your hardcoded URLs to use `https://...`.

Comment: I've made all the changes and still nothing. I just don't understand what the deal is lol... Updated my original post production code with those changes. I just can't figure it out. I know the password/username is correct because it works in local host... The only real changes should be the host/domain and port potentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out myself. The problem was that Heroku doesn't like being pushed branches so it actually was correct all along.

I ended up having to merge with the master and push the master to heroku to make it work.

There are ways to push branches to heroku however, I had trouble getting it to work even specifying that I wanted to push and run a branch.

I hope this saves someone time in the future.